# Getting a numpy array string from a csv file and converting it to a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, csv

I made some calculations with my data and saved it into a csv file.
In the file I have a cell with this string:

```
"[array([3, 3, 3]), array([3, 3, 3]), array([3, 3, 3]), array([3, 3, 3]), array([3])]"
```

I want to convert it to a valid numpy array. Tried some functions but got no luck yet.

Comment: Why do you think this is a reasonable way to serialize your array?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What do you mean?

Comment: Why do you think that putting this data into a text file like this, basically just dumping the string representation of a list, is a reasonable way to serialize your data? Why didn't you use something like JSON, or `pickle`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have pandas, use `pd.eval`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from numpy import array
>>> pd.eval("[array([3, 3, 3]), array([3, 3, 3]), array([3, 3, 3]), array([3, 3, 3]), array([3])]")
[array([3, 3, 3]), array([3, 3, 3]), array([3, 3, 3]), array([3, 3, 3]), array([3])]
>>>
```

Comment: I get the error: "array" is not a supported function

Comment: @Nikita Edited my answer with working code

Comment: If I ran it in Spyder I get the error "ValueError: unknown type object"
But if I run it in the CMD everything's working right.
Do you know what might be the issue?

Comment: Update:
Just had to specify the engine as Python